# System() function, and calling internet explorer from it, DevC++

Tags: c++, dev-c++, mingw32

I tried making a program that'd take website info, then feed it to `system()` to start website. I'm aware that characters like `(\, ",')` don't get fed to the output directly, so I used escape sequences.

I wrote this program, but the command prompt just refuses to go past `C:\` path. But if I copy paste the command displayed by my program, internet explorer gets launched. But the case isn't so for my program. Can anybody tell me where is the error?

Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

    cout<<"Please enter the website you wish to visit: ";
    string website,web;
    cin>>web;
    web= " " + web;
    website = "\"%ProgramFiles%\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore\""+web;
    cout<<"\n"<<website<<endl<<endl<<endl;
    system(website.c_str());
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using an environment variable, %ProgramFiles%, in your `system` command-line; these are specific to the MS-DOS prompt environment, and generally not available in `system` implementations.

I suggest replacing that with the full path, such as \"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore\", and see if that works.

If that works, then your implementation doesn't implicitly replace environment variables the way a full Command Prompt does, so you will need to query the environment variable separately and construct the path before you run `system`.  See [getenv](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/getenv/) for one possible way (I'm not sure what mingw32 supports, so you may have other options as well).

If that doesn't remedy the problem, I suggest checking if you can launch something simpler, like notepad.exe, to verify that there is nothing interfering with launching an application in general, such as your environment path or permissions.

Comment: This is not quite true. Environment variables are interpreted by the shell, and `system` runs via the shell. Try `system ("echo %ProgramFiles%")` and see.

Comment: Thanks. The reason I tried using %programfiles% is because I wanted to open internet explorer, no matter which drive it is in (some people, myself included, install windows in D:, or F: etc). I did try explicitly putting the path, and it did work out. I will study how I can use getenv to get the necessary path. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Pass it in **double double quotes**:

```
website = "\"\"%ProgramFiles%\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore\"\""+web;
```

The `system("something")` call actually runs the command interpreter `cmd` in a way similar (but probably not identical) to `cmd /c something`. This has implications when there are spaces in the command name, see e.g this. I cannot tell exactly why *single double quotes* work when there's no environment variable involved, and do not work otherwise, but the fact is, double double quotes do work.

If you want to launch the user's preferred browser, consider calling

```
system("start http://" + websitename);
```

instead.

Comment: Hey. Yea, adding a pair of extra " worked :D. I'd really like to know why this works and why single don't tho... I'd be grateful to anybody who'd be able to shed light to this. Also, I tried using the 2nd method, but the compiler gave me this error:  [Error] cannot convert 'std::basic_string<char>' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'int system(const char*)' . Everything aside, thanks a lot, this gave me a lot of insight.

Answer (score 1):

Get that environment variable value first.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ShlObj.h>

int main() {
    char pathToPf[MAX_PATH];
    if (S_OK == SHGetFolderPathA(NULL, CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILES, NULL, 0, pathToPf))
        std::cout << pathToPf << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[See `SHGetFolderPath` documentation...](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762181(v=vs.85).aspx)

Note that I was lazy and using the ASCII version of this function. Use it without the *A* postfix and deal with the conversation ;)

Comment: Hello. I'm not really familiar with the "ShlObj.h" header file, and what it does. I guess I have to first learn more about it(I promise to, this weekend, already added it to my to-learn list), seeing as I'm a new student that only started a while back. Thanks for the input tho, although I didn't quite get that. Sorry.

Comment: The problem with _%ProgramFiles%_ is that shell will replace this with _C:\Program Files_, and make it really hard to use it well. You have to append double double quotes, etc... `SHGetFolderPath()` will give you a char[] containing the path to program files. You can use another flags in the 2. parameter for example: `CSIDL_APPDATA`. In this case it will return something like: _C:\Users\<username>\AppData_... or whatever is in your **PATH**.